# REST parameters vs URI

Tags: rest, uri

I'm just learning REST and trying to figure out how to apply it in practice. I have a sampling of data that I want to query, but I'm not sure how the URLs are meant to be formed, i.e. where I put the query. For example, for querying the most recent 100 data records:

```
GET http://data.com/data/latest/100
GET http://data.com/data?amount=100
```

which of the previous two queries is the better, and why? And the same for the following:

```
GET http://data.com/data/latest-days/2
GET http://data.com/data?days=2
GET http://data.com/data?fromDate=01-01-2000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a remark: URLs should remain of secondary importance: REST focus on content. Which would let you free to pick the one you prefer... I personnally prefer however the query string version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would use the query string format in this case. If your `/data` path is returning all of the data, and you would like to perform this type of query, I believe it makes the most sense. You could also pass query string parameters such as `?since=01-01-2000` to get entries after a specified date or pass column names such as `?category=clothing` to retrieve all entries with category equaling clothing.

Additionally, you would want paths such as `/data/{id}` to be available to retrieve certain entries given their unique id.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on a lot of things. If you're using any sort of MVC framework, you'd use the URI segments to define your get request to your API which I personally prefer.

It's not a big deal either way, it's all based on preference and how predictable you want the URL to be to your user. In some cases, I'd say go with the REST parameters, but more often than not a URI based GET is quite clean if your setup supports it.